# I have the create and saving of the user's email, but I can't do an email update. Use firebase, firestore and react

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is my code:

```
exports.saveUserEmail = functions.region('europe-central2').auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    const email = user.email;
    const uid = user.uid;

    const dt = dateTime.create();
    const formatted = dt.format("Y-m-d H:M:S");

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set({uid: uid, email: email, created_at: formatted});
  });
```

and i tried do update like this:

```
exports.saveEditedEmail = functions.region('europe-central2').auth.user().updateUser((user, uid) => {
    const email = user.email;  
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set({uid: uid, email: email,});
})
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What is the problem? Is an error thrown or is the document not being updated at all?

Comment: yes, nothing is happening, I think I incorrectly wrote the cloud function to edit email

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any `onUpdate()` auth trigger for Cloud functions. Instead your can create a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and call it directly from client side to update your user.

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const { email } = data;
  // update email in Firebase Auth and Firestore
});
```

Alternatively, you can directly update the document in Firestore if the user tries to update their own profile. You can setup the following security rules so a user can update their own profile only:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId; 
}
```

Comment: what kind of callable function i need to create? for example .